# Find all positive integers $n$ such that $n$ divides $9^{n-1}+3^{n-1}+1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Find all positive integers $n$ such that $n$ divides $9^{n-1}+3^{n-1}+1$.

I suspect there are no solutions other than $n=1$. Assuming $n$ divides it gives $3^{3(n-1)} \equiv_n 1$, from which one might start arguing using orders mod $n$? I'm unsure of how to proceed with this observation.

Comment: If $n$ is prime this is impossible by Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: It isn't much more difficult to show that the product of two primes, necessarily both $\equiv1\pmod6$ won't work either :-(

Comment: The requirement is a bit like that of the Carmichael numbers, this time with an offset. If $n$ is a product of distinct primes, all of them $\equiv1\pmod6$, then for each prime factor $p$ of $n$ we need $$n-1\equiv \pm(\dfrac{p-1}3)\pmod {p-1}.$$ And then we need to get lucky in the sense that $3$ should not be a cubic residue modulo any of the primes :-).

Comment: Hmm. I'm no longer sure that is necessary :-(

Comment: How far have you tested (if you have spare cycles to use for such a purpose)?

Comment: Please add some context ( we are not allowed to do that ) like a search limit or particular cases so that the upvotes are actually justified since the question itself seems to meet interest of the users.

Comment: Upto $n=10^8$ , the only positive integer solution is $n=1$. Maybe , it helps to substitute $x=3^{n-1}$ leading to $n\mid x^2+x+1$ , maybe we can somehow make use of $x^2+x+1\mid x^3-1$

Comment: Also , if there is a solution $n>1$ , it must be a weak fermat pseudoprime to base $n-1$ that is it must satisfy $$27^{n-1}\equiv 1\mod n$$

Comment: Upto $n=10^{10}$ , the only positive integer solution is $n=1$.

Comment: There is no $1\lt n  \le 10^{9}$ such that $n$ divides $9^{n-1}+3^{n-1}-1$ either.

Answer (score 0):

Comment:
We rewrite the expression as:

$A_n=9^{n-1}+3^{n-1}+1=(3^{n-1}+1)^2-3^{n-1}$

If n is odd, $n=2k+1$ then we have:

$A_n=(3^{2k}+1)^2-3^{2k}=(3^{2k}+3^k+1)(3^{2k}-3^k+1)$

That is for odd n the expression is definitely a composite.

We can use this for reducing the expression to a multiple of expression of lower power; we can write:

$A_{2k+1}=B\times A_k$

where $B=(9^k-3^k+1)$

For example:

$A_{35}=B\cdot (9^{17}+3^{17}+1)$

$A_{17}=B\cdot (9^8+3^8+1)$

$(9^{8}+3^8+1)=A_9$

$A_9=B\cdot(9^{5}+3^5+1)$

$A_9=6643\times 6481=7\times 13\times 73\times 6481$

That is $A_{35}$ is a multiple of $A_9$. Also we can see that
for $n=35$ there is a common divisor $7$ in $n$ and $A_n$. We can find many such $n$ and claim that there are infinite n such that there are some common divisors in $n $ and $A_n$.That is ,at most, $n$ and $A_n$ may have some common divisors. We may also ask: Using this property, can we construct a number like n such that ,$n|9^n+3^n+1$, ?